# Controlling UI for SSRS ReportViewer for Start and End Date Picking

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

I've got a situation where I want the user to enter a start date and end date for report data. In addition there should be a drop down which allows the user to choose one of the following:

- last 7 days
- last 14 days
- last 30 days

If the user selects one of these values, the datepickers should adjust there values? I can't quite figure out how to approach this. Anyone have any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible solely from within SSRS.  However, you can still achieve your goal with a bit of extra work.  Here's a bit of pseudocode to get you going.  This technique works and we use it in our organization often.

1. In SSRS, hide the report parameters
2. Create a new blank HTML/ASPX page
3. Using only HTML, create create your own datapickers and custom "last 7 days" dropdown.
4. Use Javascript/jQuery on the client to handle your custom logic.
5. Place a "Generate Report" button on the page.
6. Insert a hidden iFrame on the page
7. When the user clicks "Generate Report", perform an HTTP POST passing the report parameters in the URL (something like http://server/reportserver?/dir/Report&rs:Command=Render&Parm1=VALUE1&Parm1=VALUE2&Parm1=VALUE3)
8. Display the report in the iFrame

Your users won't know the difference and this will give you total control over the layout and presentation of your report parameters.

Comment: Thanks Alison-- this is helpful. We're trying to avoid creating our own custom UI. But I'll keep this option open. Thanks again!

Comment: @ek_ny: I hear ya.  More code means more maintenance for the next guy.  If you do find a different solution, please post it here for others to see.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this within in SSRS.  Not great but acceptable.
Have the first parameter be a pick list with two choices.
  Pick Dates or Last X Days.
  Have the next parameter be the start date.
  The third parameter is another pick list.  It is either a list of dates or a list of numbers depending on the choice they made in the beginning.

Another way would be to have two reports displayed to the user.  one with an open date range and one with a predefined pick list of dates.  These would be linked reports that call the same underlying report but display different parameters.  This is the approach I would take for such a user request.